# can't make slideDown work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to slideDown a (person's bio) div under a row of 3 buttons, each button with a name of a person. Click a button and the appropriate person's bio slides down under it.
I've given the button and the corresponding person's bio div I want to slideDown the same class. 
Ultimately, when a button is clicked, I'd like to animate the currently shown person's bio so it shoots off the right side of the screen, and then the bio that goes with the button that was clicked will slide down. I've noticed that if something is set to display:none is my style sheet, that I can't animate it, but if I set an element to display:none in my JS right before I slideDown, it works.

```
<div class="about-btn-bar">
  <div class="about-btn-diane"><a class="diane" href="#">Diane</a></div>
  <div class="about-btn-juli"><a class="juli"  href="#">Juli</a></div>
  <div class="about-btn-stephanie"><a class="stephanie" href="#">Stephanie</a></div>  
</div>

<div class="bios-wrapper">
   <div class="about-diane diane">
        <img width="160" height="180" src="images/diane.jpg">
        <p class="bio">Diane's bio here.</p>    
   </div>
   <div class="about-juli juli">
        <img src="images/juli.jpg">
        <p class="bio">Juli bio here.</p>   
   </div>
   <div class="about-stephanie stephanie">
        <img src="images/stephanie.jpg">
        <p class="bio">Stephanie bio here.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.bios-wrapper div{
    position: absolute;
    padding-bottom: 75px;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    left:0px;
    top:150px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('.about-btn-bar a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var myClass = $(this).attr("class");
        $('.bios-wrapper div').class(myClass).slideDown("slow");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/AkeQipUY/2/edit)**

```
$('.about-btn-bar a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.bios-wrapper .'+ this.className).slideDown("slow");
});
```

If you want to slideUp previously opened elements this might come quite handy:

```
$('.about-btn-bar a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.bios-wrapper > div').slideUp(800);
  $('.bios-wrapper .'+ this.className).stop().slideDown(800);
});
```

If you need to also toggle an already opened one:

```
$('.about-btn-bar a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.bios-wrapper > div').slideUp(800);
  $('.bios-wrapper .'+ this.className).stop().slideToggle(800);
});
```

Comment: The second bit of code has both movements taking place simultaneously. One is going up while another is going down. I tried a callback, but it doesn't work either: ...slideUp(800,function(){...

Comment: @james I'm sure you'll find a solution with the given examples.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** I've updated this to hide the previous content before the `slideDown()`:

```
$('.about-btn-bar').on('click', 'a', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $myClass = $('.'+$(this).attr('class'));

    $('.bios-wrapper div').hide();
    $myClass.slideDown('fast');
});
```

**[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yk3WE/1/)**

Comment: You say: "*Its recommended to move away from .click() and try .on(), with that in mind try this:*"... Can you please add an official surce where it's stated that `.click()` method is now deprecated?

Comment: unfortunately, this will slideDown all that are clicked but doesn't slideUp the one that is already down, so they can appear all on top of each other. try it.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, good point, thanks for pointing that out. Officially `.click()` is a shortcut for `.on('click')` as of 1.7 I think. But is not deprecated as `.delegate()` is. I'll edit my post. [api on .click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)